# Modelling a simple database - Bill splitting app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn to model SQL databases, and am having some trouble understanding some concepts.  I want to a build an app, where users can split a bill at a restaurant.  Could someone please tell me if the following is allowed?

I have Bills, Items, and Users

```
Bill has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
Bill has_many :users, foreign_key: :user_id
User has_many :bills, foreign_key: :created_by
Item belongs_to :bill
```

**Is it ok for a user to have many bills, and a bill to have many users?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more fundamental database design issue. If I were to design this database for a bill sharing app, it would be like this

user.rb

```
has_many :bill_contributions
has_many :bills, through: :bill_contributions
```

bill.rb

```
has_many :items
has_many :bill_contributions
has_many :users, through: :bill_contributions
```

bill_contribution.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :bill
```

---

I split it like this because there is a has many and belongs to many relationship between the user and bills as a user can have a lot of bills and bills can be split among many users. you can look up HABTM 
database relationships if you wish to learn more